# Applozic - Encryption and local host

Tags: applozic

We are developing an App where the chat is the most important function. I would like to know if using Applozic the chat could be encrypted (because the app has to be Hipaa compliant), and if the data could be resident in a local host (because of local regulations).

Answer (score 1):

Yes chat can be encrypted, you can get in touch with us at support@applozic.com